# Vim resets &lines if system() gets called befor the gui starts

Tags: debugging, vim, settings

I have a strange problem with gVim and setting the number of lines. To recreate the problem, make a temporary .vimrc-file with the following lines:

```
1 if has('gui')
2     set lines=40
3 endif
4 let test=system('ls')
5 echo test
```

If vim is now started from a terminal with its gui (gvim or vim -g), you would expect `&lines=40`. What happens is that `&lines` is first set to 40 as expected on line 2, then it is reset on line 4 when the `system('ls')` is called. Thus `&lines/=40` on line 5. Further it seems like `&lines` will be set to whatever the environment variable `$LINES` is set to.

Any help identifying what the problem is will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

How about putting `set lines=999` in your `~/.gvimrc` file?  That looks to be the last script that is sourced when running `gvim`.

You can see what files are getting sourced and in what order with the following command:

```
:scriptnames
```

Also, the following should tell you what script `lines` was last set in (or any other option for that matter):

```
:verbose set lines?
```

Comment: Hi! I could use a .gvimrc-file as you suggest, and this does work. But somehow gvim then takes a very long time to load, so I think I still need to fix the presented bug. Personally I have kept everything in my vimrc-file and use has('gui')-conditionals for gvim-settings. Anyway, thanks for you answer. The :scriptnames and :verbose <something> commands are useful, but I have not been able to locate the bug yet.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like 'lines' setting is reset when gui is entered. Try replacing `set lines=40` with one of the following:

```
autocmd GuiEnter * set lines=40

call feedkeys("\<C-\>\<C-n>:set lines=40\n", 'n')

autocmd GuiEnter * call feedkeys("\<C-\>\<C-n>:set lines=40\n", 'n')
```

Comment: I think I should have added a line in the example vimrc-file. If you do, and then start vim in debug mode and check the value of &lines right after the system call is finished, but _before_ the gui has started. In fact, to make this clear, I will update the question. Anyway, the point is that &lines is not reset when the gui is entered, it is reset when or right after the system function is called.

Comment: @Karl Yngve Lervåg On my system it is reset when gui is entered, no matter whether there is or there is not `system()` call. But I now added three :echomsg's and I see that 'lines' option is reset after system() call to the value it had before `set lines` was run. I don't think it should be fixed: if it is reset when gui is entered, it does not matter whether or not it is reset by `system()` call.

Comment: I disagree. It should not be reset when the gui is entered. And on my system this works as expected. I only have a problem with the `&lines` setting after adding a `system()` call in the initialization process.